# Is there a way to trigger a function after the previous function ends?

Tags: javascript

I would like to run the function step2() after the function startGame() ends.

```
function startGame() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("X");
    document.getElementById("3x3").appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("3x3").style.fontSize = "120px";
}
function step2() {
    while (document.getElementById("3x1").innerHTML == "") {
    }
}
```

Comment: Then make a call to `step2()` at the end of `startGame`

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: `step2()` seems to be an infinite loop. Unless there's something inside the `while` that changes the HTML, the value of the condition will never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function startGame() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("X");
    document.getElementById("3x3").appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("3x3").style.fontSize = "120px";
    step2();
}
function step2() {
    // Step 2 logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the functions one after the other:

```
startGame();
step2();
```

Statements are simply executed in sequence, so when the first function call returns, the next function call is done.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! You *could* look into Promises -- either the ES6-supplied version or using a library like Bluebird. Promises allow you to chain a method onto a function so that it will complete functions synchronously.

In your case, however, you could just make a call to `step2()` at the end of `startGame`.

Comment: Promises are generally only needed for async functions. There's nothing asynchronous here.